# Why can't light deflect a freely suspended magnet if it is an EM wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Light is an EM wave but why doesn't it deflect a magnet or show magnetic interaction with magnetic particles?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line, MRI, electron paramagnetic resonance. Light does interact with magnetic moments.